# How to detect undefined imports (when using javascript es6 import statements)

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I often run into the problem of an javascript es6 import statement (transpilled via babel) failing to actually find the file the developer intended. This is particularly concerning during refactoring or during auto-fixing/formatting.

Is there a way to automatically flag imports, that are bringing in `undefined`? **edit**: at runtime?

Comment: If you are using eslint you could include import plugin with this rule on https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md If not I do recommend you to ;)

Comment: And to automate the thing you could use `husky` pre-commit hook to run by `lint-staged` linters over staged files. There are lots of articles on how to use husky, lint-staged, prettier, eslint together

Comment: Ah, thanks Yury, that looks like something I need to check

Comment: Ah, thats a great idea. But unfortunately in my case, the eslint autofixed code does _not_ work. So I actually need something at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard practice to have a developer console of some kind or another (such as Chrome Developer Tools - hit F12, if working on web pages) open during refactoring or development of the Javascript.

So any imports that are not found would generate errors in that console, and thus be visible to the developer.

Missing imports however are not of concern (or should not be) to the User, and far as I know there is no mechanism to flag this to a User (non-developer) of the page. Dood design dictates it is not something they should be concerned with.

So you're probably thinking okay, during development time the we detect during our refactoring via the console that some imports have gone missing, we fix them and publish the latest code/page. Later the imports go missing.

Well that's the thing. If the imports live on external sources and can just randomly go missing, you need to fix That problem. If the imports need to live locally (same location as the javascript being served up) so they are available with 100% accuracy, then do that.

Comment: "any imports that are not found would generate errors in that console" that is not true for any js platforms I have ever encountered. I am curious if dynamic es6 imports in browsers do this.

Comment: I don't see how this really addresses the question, which is how to automatically detect bad imports. The errors happen during execution (because something is undefined), not during the importing code. This question is attempting to understand how to deal w/ this type of error prior to things blowing up.

Comment: If an import fails at runtime, things have already "blown up". It's not something to solve at runtime or something that the user (ie: while the page is running) should have to "detect". And it is surprising to hear that for example, Chrome, does not throw errors in its console when it cannot load a resource in your page whether that be an image, external script, or a url, since i'm sitting here re-testing it right now and in the console for nearly every public page on the web you can see it throw these errors constantly (If you bother to open it).

Comment: @JohnFantastico ah we are getting our wires crossed. I'm talking about a language feature of javascript version es6! Not a conceptual import of resources! http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html I have edited my question for clarity - sorry for the confusion

Comment: My mistake too, I overlooked that the question was more specific to es6, thanks.

Comment: @JohnFantastico Yes, they have--the OP is asking how to avoid that by analyzing the source. This has nothing to do with UX, it's about developer experience and how to statically avoid these types of errors.